# What's the difference between policy vs permission based access control?

Tags: authorization, access-control

I am newbie at these stuff and while I was able to distinguish between `role-based` vs. `policy-based` authorization models, I can't seem to understand whether there is one between policy-based vs. permission-based. On a conceptual level, what is the difference between them? Can `policy` and `permission` terms be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The classic example of policy based auth, which I'm sure you have seen if you have googled, is a alcohol selling app, which in (normal countries) would read:

```
Allow user if user.age > 18
```

this is apposed to role based which would read...

```
Allow user if user.role is in {"Adult"}
```

or permissions based which would read

```
Allow user if user.permission == "CanBuyAlcohol"
```

The benefit of the role based is obvious when you consider that the rules which put someone in a role can be arbitrary. For example some countries alcohol is illegal and some have different ages, you can see how your authentication code can become complex

```
if(!user.country.IsInLockdown)
{
    If user.country == UK
       Allow user if user.age > 18
    else if user.country = "US"
       //check local state laws
       Allow user if user.age > 21
    else if user.country.religion == Muslim && ! user.IsTourist
       return false
...
```

Obviously with role based auth you still have to do this somewhere to see if you can put someone in the various roles. But this can be delegated to a human or a separate specific bit of software rather than being embedded in your application, which might not care about these details.

Permission based is considered problematic because you end up with a massive grid of users and permissions that's impossible to maintain.

```
userid, canBuyAlcohol, canBuyCigarettes, canPlayInBallPit
1, yes, yes, no
2, no, no, yes
3, no, yes, yes ?!?
```